# Распознать текст C#

Tags: c#, opencv, captcha, emgucv

**Хочу разгадать капчу.**

С помощью Emgu.CV (OpenCV для C#) немного почистил изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее необходимо распознать символы. Tesseract просто так не найдёт их, так как символы неплохо искажены. Решил обучить нейронку. Понарезал символов (пример для буквы "g"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал заюзать FANN. Обучил, что бы она выдавала по картинке число, которое соответсвует нужному символу. Но как найти отдельный символ на картинке, что бы его передать в нейронку? Обычно это делают нахождением контура, но тут такое не прокатит, всё слипается и Emgu.CV мне нашёл всего 1 контур для всех символов сразу.

Есть вариант создания Хаар-каскадов для каждой буквы, обучать их умею. Но кажется довольно неоптимпальным учить каждую букву как отдельный каскад, ещё и негативные примеры придётся нарезать.

**Главный вопрос:** как лучше найти отдельный символ на картинке, что б потом просто его распознать?

Если есть идеи по-лучше, буду только рад услышать!

Comment: Взламывать капчи - целая наука, и идей там море. Я на самом деле удивлен, что вы с этим вопросом пришли сюда, так как материалов и библиотек уже понаписанных на эту тему гораздо больше, чем вы перечислили. И раз капчи еще существуют, значит универсального распознавателя до сих пор не придумано. Задача творческая. Могу только одно подсказать, если вы обучаете сеть, то обучайте ее и искать то что ей надо найти на картинке, самостоятельно. Задача найти кота на фотке вроде эталонная для того чтобы показать на что способна нейронка сама по себе, без примочек.

Comment: @aepot понятно что вариантов море, но я ищу какую-либо альтернативу обучению хаар каскада, потому что он как раз хорошо умеет находить объекты на картинке, но обучать его для каждой буквы это немного перебор

Comment: Напишите свой генератор капчей или утащите где-нибудь готовый, и развлекайте свой каскад в автоматическом режиме.

Comment: @aepot свой генератор это хорошо, но вряд-ли получиться прям такие же капчи, тут как минимум специфический шрифт